# About youtube v3 api quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I develop a project about my company, I use youtube v3 api that upload a edited video.
We want to launch our service, but we could upload only 6 videos in a day. Because our account have 10000 quotas.
We should launch this service in August at the least.

I applied for a quota increase through the Google form, but is there a faster way or a way to get a quicker response?